# Accessing the menu button using only a mouse

Tags: mouse, menu

I got my first tablet (Samsung Galaxy Tab A (2017), running Android 7.1.1).  I am physically disabled, and I'm unable to actually touch the screen.  But I can use a computer mouse, so thanks to [Android's support for mouse control via a USB OTG cable](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/clever-adapter-connects-usb-accessories-to-your-android-device/), I'm able to use the operating system and do most everything.

One thing I haven't found in the operating system, though, is a Menu button like this:

[image: menu button]

My tablet does have a physical/hardware Menu button -- the button to the left of the home button -- like in this photo:

[image: tablet photo]

But since I can't press physical buttons on the tablet, **I want to access the Menu with the mouse only, in the operating system.  Is this possible?**

Comment: Doubling those hardware buttons to software buttons would help, do I understand that correctly? If so, you could check with my list of apps to [Edit Key Settings](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_settings#group_546). [Assistive Touch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.att.swipe.assistivetouch) sounds like a candiate, promising e.g. virtual back+home buttons (just forget about that RAM booster included). If your device is rooted, you'd have some additional possibilities.

Comment: @Izzy Correct, doubling the hardware buttons to software buttons would help so much!

Comment: Thought so :) Were you able to try one of those apps? Did any work out in the desired way? Feel free to write up an answer then though the idea was mine (you could of course mention that fact) and accept it.